# Complex roots of equation $z^\mu=r$

Tags: complex-numbers

> Find the complex roots of equation concerning unknown complex number $z$
>   \begin{equation}
> z^\mu=r,\quad \mu>0,r\in\pmb{R}
> \end{equation}

A solution given by a book is to only consider the principal branch of $z$, in my opinion, I think we should consider all the branches.

The following is my solution
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
z^\mu&=\text{exp}(\mu(\text{Ln}(z)))\\
&=\text{exp}(\mu(\text{ln}(z)+i\text{Arg}(z)+i2k \pi))\\
&=|z|^\mu\text{exp}(\mu(i\text{Arg)(z)+i2k\pi)},\quad -\pi<\text{Arg}(z)\le\pi\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}

If $r<0$, then $r=|r|\text{exp}(i\pi)$. Consequently,
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&|z|^\mu=|r|\\
&\text{Arg}(z)=\frac{(1-2k)\pi}{\mu}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Choose those $k$'s such that $-\pi<\frac{(1-2k)\pi}{\mu}\le\pi$.

But the book only considers the principal branch that corresponds to $k=0$. I don't see why other branches are not considered?

Can someone give me an explanation? Thank you

Comment: When $z$ is complex and $\mu$ real non integer, $z^\mu$ is *undefined*. Hence the problem does not make sense. What is your source?

Comment: Your solution looks fine. As for your book, it depends on the language in which the problem was stated. Perhaps it just asked for one solution as opposed to all solutions.

Comment: @Did: For real exponents, although $z^\mu$ is not well-defined as a single value, it is well-defined as a set-valued function in the manner that the OP wrote.

Comment: @LeeMosher I find problematic to reconcile your interpretation with the OP's formulation "Find the complex roots of equation concerning unknown complex number $z$
$z^\mu=r$". Here $r$ is a number hence $z^\mu$ can only be a number, not a set of numbers (not to mention that I have never seen the notation $z^\mu$ stand for a set of complex numbers). Your first comment to the OP is also in contradiction with the question's text since the question says "Find **the** complex roots...", not "one solution".

Comment: @ecook I fail to remember, at your "reputation", can one comments one's own questions?

Comment: @Did Sorry for my late reply. Actually, this problem originates from studying the stability of a system, i.e., if the above system has roots, then the system is unstable, otherwise it is stable. However, if only principal branch is conidered, the conclusion is a stable system, which is stated by the book I read. However, if all branches are investigated, the opposite conclusion should be made.